# What API should I look for to show UIButtons or UITableViewCells in a UIView, on the bottom of the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know, what I want, but I don't know, what am I looking for.

Example:

When the user `taps` and `holds` an image, in safari, `3 UITableViewCells` appear on the bottom. Save Image; Copy and Cancel.

Is there an `API` for this? Maybe in the likes of an `UIDocumentInteractionController`, that is not for documents.

If not, what's a good known approach  to do it?

I know, how to do a custom implement of it, but am trying to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`UIActionSheet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

This allows you to show options for something and you can present it from a view, a tab bar or a toolbar, depending on your needs.

If you use `showInView:`on iPad, it will be presented centered on the screen.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you Sir. I'll accept your answer in 13 minutes.